# Inno Setup Choose a directory to install files from a pre-defined set

Tags: directory, inno-setup

In this situation, I need to install a file to specific directory, but in different computer it might be in different folder so I need to check which on is correct.

For example, I have a file and it needs to install in `A` folder or `B` folder or `C` folder, depends on the computer has `A` or `B` or `C`. So I need to check them first, if the computer has `B`, then install the file in the `B` folder, etc.

I know I can use check after file's `DestDir`, if the directory doesn't exist then it won't install anything, but what I need is install that file to other directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you do not want to allow the user to select the destination folder on the "Select Destination Location"? Instead you want to automatically pick the location, depending on the location exists on the target machine already, right?

Comment: Isn't there a way to select the correct location somehow (like reading some registry key), instead of trying a hard-coded set of directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup), check for existence of your pre-defined set of directories and remember the one you find. Then set the default installation path to the found one using a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) in the [`DefaultDirName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_defaultdirname).

You will possible also want to set the [`DisableDirPage=yes`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage) and the [`UsePreviousAppDir=no`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_usepreviousappdir).

```pascal
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetDirName}
DisableDirPage=yes
UsePreviousAppDir=no

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]

var
  DirName: string;

function TryPath(Path: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := DirExists(Path);
  if Result then
  begin
    Log(Format('Path %s exists', [Path]))
    DirName := Path;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Path %s does not', [Path]))
  end;
end;

function GetDirName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := DirName;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    TryPath('C:\path1') or
    TryPath('C:\path2') or
    TryPath('C:\path3');

  if Result then
  begin
    Log(Format('Destination %s selected', [DirName]))
  end
    else
  begin
    MsgBox('No destination found, aborting installation', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Instead of using `DefaultDirName={code:GetDirName}`, you can also use `DestDir: "{code:GetDirName}"` in the respective entries of the `[Files]` section, if appropriate.

Comment: May I ask if C:\path1 and C:\path2 are exist, and I want the file both install to these folders, not only in one path, how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: @SabrinaLiu You need two separate entries in the `Files` section. One for each folder.